# How curvature and field strength are exactly the same?

Tags: differential-geometry, general-relativity

I am watching these lecture series by Fredric Schuller.

[Curvature and torsion on principal bundles - Lec 24 - Frederic Schuller](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j36o4DLLK2k&list=PLPH7f_7ZlzxTi6kS4vCmv4ZKm9u8g5yic&index=24) @minute 34:00

In this part he discusses the Lie algebra valued one and two forms on the principal bundle that are pulled back to the base manifold.

He shows the relationship between general relativity and electromagnetism in the classical theory.

He emphasize that for instance that the curvature of space-time is exactly the same as the non-abelian Yang-Mills field strength.

It is not clear to me in what sense they are "exactly" the same.

Isn't the physical electromagnetism filed strength tensor a real valued object and abelian?

Comment: The Riemann curvature tensor can be represented by the local field strength of a connection in the frame bundle $FM$, the associated principal bundle to the tangent bundle $TM$. In electromagnetism the principal bundle over $M$ is not the frame bundle but some $U(1)$-bundle (which group is Abelian). Does this make it any clearer? I could say something/give a reference about the connection between curvature on the frame bundle and the Riemann curvature tensor if that would be of help.

Comment: @mcwiggler 
So is it right to say that in the case of electromagnetism the Lie group U(1) is different from the case of the general relativity Lie group which is GL? Otherwise, curvature and field strength are exactly the same?

Comment: For the first sentence: it is right, at least roughly; I haven't studied the physics of either case in depth. The Riemannian curvature and the field strength are not exactly the same: the Riemannian curvature is a global object, a 2-tensor with values in the endomorphism bundle $\text{End}(TM)$, while the field strength is by definition a local object (unless the principal bundle is trivial). The field strength gives a local matrix representation of the curvature.